# Handling Screen Orientation - Android

Tags: android

I am having a problem in screen orienation in my application. I created an alternate layout in res/layout-lan folder for landscape mode. The problem occurred during orientation change,

1.An activity get recreated without destroying the old activity.

2.since i am using mediaplayer in my app,on screen rotation the .mp3 is playing on both orientation concurrently..

I am unable to find proper sample code for handling screen orientation with saving and restoring the state of the activity..............

Answer (score 3):

> 1.An activity get recreated without destroying the old activity.

The recreation of the `Activity` is the natural default behavior of Android when a configuration change occurs.  The likely reason your old Activity lingers in memory is because it is referencing a currently playing instance of a `MediaPlayer`.

Because you are using different layout resources for landscape and portrait, it is to your advantage to let Android recreate the Activity and pull the appropriate resources each time.  If you handle rotation yourself, you will be responsible to reloading the proper layout as well.

> 2.since i am using mediaplayer in my app,on screen rotation the .mp3 is playing on both orientation concurrently..

There are two solutions to this issue...

The ideal solution is to move your media playback into a `Service`.  The `Activity` can call the `Service` to start/stop/etc. playback when directed by the user, but putting this into a background component like a `Service` allows it to operate continuously even when your `Activity` is in flux due to the changes.  This is the design pattern the Android team encourages, where your `Activity` really only deals with   user interface.

Another workable solution is to pass your `MediaPlayer` from the old `Activity` to the new one using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.  This allows the single `MediaPlayer` to exist between `Activity` instances, keeping the playback consistent.  For example:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Check if we have a player passed in from the last instance
        mPlayer = (MediaPlayer)getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        //If not, make a new one
        if (mPlayer == null) {
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
           //...Set up new player instance...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        //Clear our member variable to guarantee this Activity
        // is allowed to GC after onDestroy()
        MediaPlayer instance = mPlayer;
        mPlayer = null;
        //Hand our current player up to the next Activity to be created
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Another option to ensure the best memory cleanup would be to define `mPlayer` as a `WeakReference<MediaPlayer>` to allow the GC to claim the old `Activity`, even if the `MediaPlayer` is playing audio at the time of the configuration change.

Comment: Happy to help.  If this answer was useful to you, please feel free to accept or upvote it.  Cheers!

Comment: In my application having two instances of Mediaplayer like mplayer and mplayer1 .can i be able to retain both the instance simulatenously.....

Comment: You can only retain one object, but that object could be a collection (i.e. `List` or `Map`) so you could pack your instances into a collection object and retain that instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can stop recreation of activity when Screen orientation changed by below steps.

set configChanges tag as below

```
 <activity android:name=".Activity_name"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

use below method.

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
   // to do on orientation changed          
    }
    }
```

Comment: OP Beware that if this approach is used, you must call `setContentView()` again manually in order for the alternative layout to be picked up and drawn.  By default, it will just rotate the `Activity` and keep the same layout in place.

Comment: i am placing the landscape layout in layout-land folder.......can you please tell me how to avoid recreation of activity by this method ...

Comment: in onCOnfichange you can check which orientation it is, and do needful

Answer (score 0):

```
                       v
```

Create Folder **res/layout-land**

Instead of res/layout-**lan**   <---- put here **d** in folder-name

Answer (score 0):

```
//by changing the orientation if your layout not disturb in design just data
```

//destroyed
//then use the below attribute in manifest in activity you want to do

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"

//but your whole screen design disturb then turn off orientation by using this

 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```